# Kivy: How to switch buttons by dragging over them

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, touch

I have created an array of buttons in Kivy, and I need to switch their states (or change color/background) by touch-dragging over them. I can't figure out how to do it. The task is to create words by dragging over letter buttons. Should I use an invisible Scatter widget, or is there something dedicated for this purpose. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Scatter would be a way, but it’s not necessary, you can implement `on_touch_down`, `on_touch_move` and `on_touch_up` methods of your widget class to handle being dragged and dropped other things, you’ll need to test collision of the dragged widget with possible landing zones (widgets) during drag and drop, to decide how to react to them, i have this example https://gist.github.com/tshirtman/7282822

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.garden.magnet import Magnet
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

from os import listdir

IMAGEDIR = '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/'

IMAGES = filter(
    lambda x: x.endswith('.png'),
    listdir(IMAGEDIR))

kv = '''
FloatLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        GridLayout:
            id: grid_layout
            cols: int(self.width / 32)
        FloatLayout:
            id: float_layout
'''


class DraggableImage(Magnet):
    img = ObjectProperty(None, allownone=True)
    app = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_img(self, *args):
        self.clear_widgets()

        if self.img:
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda *x: self.add_widget(self.img), 0)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch, *args):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            touch.grab(self)
            self.remove_widget(self.img)
            self.app.root.add_widget(self.img)
            self.center = touch.pos
            self.img.center = touch.pos
            return True

        return super(DraggableImage, self).on_touch_down(touch, *args)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch, *args):
        grid_layout = self.app.root.ids.grid_layout
        float_layout = self.app.root.ids.float_layout

        if touch.grab_current == self:
            self.img.center = touch.pos
            if grid_layout.collide_point(*touch.pos):
                grid_layout.remove_widget(self)
                float_layout.remove_widget(self)

                for i, c in enumerate(grid_layout.children):
                    if c.collide_point(*touch.pos):
                        grid_layout.add_widget(self, i - 1)
                        break
                else:
                    grid_layout.add_widget(self)
            else:
                if self.parent == grid_layout:
                    grid_layout.remove_widget(self)
                    float_layout.add_widget(self)

                self.center = touch.pos

        return super(DraggableImage, self).on_touch_move(touch, *args)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch, *args):
        if touch.grab_current == self:
            self.app.root.remove_widget(self.img)
            self.add_widget(self.img)
            touch.ungrab(self)
            return True

        return super(DraggableImage, self).on_touch_up(touch, *args)


class DnDMagnet(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(kv)
        for i in IMAGES:
            image = Image(source=IMAGEDIR + i, size=(32, 32),
                          size_hint=(None, None))
            draggable = DraggableImage(img=image, app=self,
                                       size_hint=(None, None),
                                       size=(32, 32))
            self.root.ids.grid_layout.add_widget(draggable)

        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DnDMagnet().run()
```

(see comments on the gist for possible improvements though, i didn’t try them but they seem to make sense)

Which depends on the magnet widget (https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.magnet) for nice effects, but this is not strictly necessary for you either, the important part is understanding the role of the `on_touch_*` methods and grabbing (grabbing makes sure a widget that started caring about a touch, gets all the updates for this touch, whatever other widgets think about it).

there is also a DragBehavior https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.drag.html but i don’t see events in the documentation allowing to check collision on drop, that i think you need, but possibly subclassing this widget and implementing your changes in your subclass would be easier, as my example predates it, i didn’t try.